# Mailchimp / Foundation Inc Problems in Gmail

Tags: css, email

I've coded a custom mailchimp template with Inc. 
Everything looks as i expected. But i have some problems with GMAIL in the Desktop-view: 
The Images (Logos) for the the Mobile-view are visible in GMAIL Desktop view. 
The "show-for-small" class will not be processed in GMAIL...

https://jsbin.com/lewovi/edit?html,output

[image: GMAIl-Account. Desktop and Mobile Logos are visible]

[image: Apple Mail]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using inline styles instead of using classes?

From Mailchimp pages (http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/ways-to-build/css-in-html-email)

> Use inline CSS Because browser-based email applications, such as
>   Gmail, strip out head and body tags by default, always use inline
>   CSS over embedded CSS.

Comment: i've pasted my code in the mailchimp css inliner tool.
unfortunately same result in GMAIL:
https://jsbin.com/lapeca/edit?html,output

Comment: From what I read, Gmail does not respect media queries. I have found this article that describes an approach that you could use: https://litmus.com/community/code/543-mailbox-app-and-gmail-app-media-query-support